# undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

app uses rails 2.2.2
getting the following error on rake gem install

thanks!

```
D:\web>rake gems:install --trace
(in D:/web)
rake aborted!
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:223:in `activate'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
D:/web/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support.rb:56
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
D:/web/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/misc.rake:18
D:/web/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `load'
D:/web/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4
D:/web/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `each'
D:/web/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
D:/web/Rakefile:10
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `run'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
C:/Ruby/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/Ruby/bin/rake:19

D:\web>
```

Comment: could you reformat your question, making the entire stacktrace formatted as code (select it and press the "101010" button)? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mustn't use rake gems:install with old rails version.
Main problem tht may be installed gem version that isn't supported with current application version.(if version not set strictly)

But now problem is with plugin railties. 
So you should rename vendor directory and try rake gems:install (or better try to install each gem separately with minimal version required by gem install somegem -v= )

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue before, and it basically comes down to "which gem is messing things up?". I just saw this with a vendored gem that had a .specification file that locked rails = 2.3.8 (and I was upgrading to 2.3.9)

I'm on rubygems 1.3.7 (so maybe this would have been easier to figure out in a newer version)

I figured it out by going in to my local railties.../gem_dependency.rb file and changing this method:

```
 def add_load_paths
      self.class.add_frozen_gem_path
      return if @loaded || @load_paths_added
      if framework_gem?
        @load_paths_added = @loaded = @frozen = true
        return
      end
      gem self
      @spec = Gem.loaded_specs[name]
      @frozen = @spec.loaded_from.include?(self.class.unpacked_path) if @spec
      @load_paths_added = true
    rescue Gem::LoadError
    end
```

to replace Gem::LoadError with Exception
  ....

```
 rescue Exception
   puts "problem with gem #{name}"
  end
```

then I ran rake gems (a simple test to see that things are loaded ok) and it showed me the two gems that were locked to specific versions, and I was able to make changes to their .specification files to lift the restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `rake gem install --trace` but `rake gems:install --trace`.

`gem install` is the command to manually install gems.
`gems:install` is the rake task that Rails provides for installing gems mentioned in your config.